# Linux Mint Live-USB skips Grub menu and boots straight to desktop

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, live-usb

As it says in the title, my Linux Mint 19.1 Cinnamon 64-bit Live-USB boots straight to desktop.

Normally, this is not a problem since it works otherwise, but I can't do OEM installs with this since it wont go to Grub.

I haven't modified the ISO or the Live-media in any way. I just downloaded it from Linux Mint homepage (back when 19.1 version was released), and flashed it to the USB-stick.

When I boot to the Live-USB, there is a Linux Mint splash picture on the screen and it starts a countdown from 10, saying "Automatic boot in X" (X being the counter number). After that it boots to desktop.

Do I have to interrupt the automatic boot to enter the Grub menu? Most of the other distros I've tried have booted into the Grub first.

EDIT: I flashed the ISO with Rufus (has worked on most ISO's, also does not mess up USB-stick like Etcher), and it was MBR.

Comment: @K7AAY flashed with Rufus and it was MBR. I've verified the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I just needed to press ESC during the automatic boot and the screen moved to the Grub menu.